# Helps with a regression analysis with confounded predictors

Tags: regression, residuals, confounding

I want to run a regression analysis with the following variables:

- Y = Dependent variable
- X1 = Independent variable 1
- X2 = X1/Z = Independent variable 2

Note that X1 and X2 are confounded because both are based on X1 (i.e., X2 is the ratio of X1 with another variable, Z).

There is a positive relation between X1 and Y. I would like to know if there is an effect of X2 on Y over and above any effect of X1 on Y.

Someone told me that I should look at the "residual effect", but I do not know what that means.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $X1$ and $X2$ are not necessarily confounded.  After all, perhaps $Z$ is the product of $X1$ and a variable independent of $X2$.  *The mechanics* of creating variables does not (in itself) imply anything about what they mean or how they might behave in a statistical model.  Thus, your question reduces to asking "how do I regress $Y$ against two variables $X1$ and $X2$."  See [tag:multiple-regression].

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm answering your question.I assume y = b1*X1+b2*X2+e

If Z is a constant, then X1 and X2 are effectively the same and one should be dropped.

In my next 3 cases, both X1 and X2 would have "separate, possibly correlated effects on y. The details of the effect would depend on the details of the variables.

If Z is a deterministic function, X2 = X1/Z(X1), (for example Z = 1/(X1)), then this would be a non-linear regression done as a linear one (X2 = X1^2, polynomial fit).

If Z is a random variable, then X2/Z is a random variable, and this is a bivariate regression with a correlation coefficient. A simple example is X2 = X1 + e (corresponding to Z = X1/(X1+e) where e is a randomly distributed variate independent of X1), means X1 and X2 are correlated RVs and the correlation coefficient is independent of predictors and we get a simple OLS. You might find this helpful.
https://github.com/sabrawer/machine-learning/blob/master/generating%20correlated%20random%20variables.pdf

If Z is a different RV than above, if we can write X2=X1+e, then e becomes a function of X1. This would not be a standard bivariate regression as the correlation matrix would be a function of X1. There is nothing wrong with this, it is just that problem could not be handled as an OLS regression.